# VirusTotalNet does not work offline in .NET Core 7

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-core, antivirus, virus-scanning

I use the VirusTotalNet library, but this library works online. If I want it to be offline, what library should I use so that I can get the information daily and then I can find the virus file offline?

I also want the desired library to work in Iran and not be sanctioned.

```
VirusTotal v = new VirusTotal("****");

FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo("d:\\test.txt");

FileReport fileReport = await v.GetFileReportAsync(fileInfo);

ScanResult fi = await v.ScanFileAsync(fileInfo);
```

**The error text that I receive if the device is offline:**

```
No such host is known. (www.virustotal.com:443)
```

Comment: you may want to ask your question here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: eg. https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/81276/command-line-anti-virus-scanner-for-offline-usage

Comment: What is the difference with this part? @RandRandom

Comment: what do you mean with "this part"?

Comment: What is the difference between softwarerecs.stackexchange.com and https://stackoverflow.com? @RandRandom

Comment: seeking recommendation for tools, libaries is offtopic on stackoverflow -  as you can find explained here:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic `Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.`

Answer (score 1):

[`VirusTotalNet`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/VirusTotalNet) nuget on its [website](https://github.com/Genbox/VirusTotalNet/) states that:

> VirusTotal.NET - A full implementation of the VirusTotal 2.0 API

Because it's an API client, it requires access to the internet

Comment: Is there another library that can be downloaded online and then I can scan the files of the device offline.